# Getting Symphony Error when getting header inside middleware of Laravel

Tags: laravel, http, middleware

I'm getting this error

> Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::addHeaders() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response, null given,

When getting header inside the middleware of Laravel 5.7
Here's my code in the middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if($request->header('Authorization')) {
        return $next($request);
    }

    return response()->json([
        'message' => 'Not a valid API request.',
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that the `header()` function you are calling is not doing what you expect it to do.